# policy-map apply using Linux Centos

Tags: linux, centos, cisco

In Cisco i can found this

```
object-group network XYZ
10.10.10.0 255.255.255.192

object-group network ABC
10.10.11.0 255.255.255.192

class-map match-any C-XYZ 
 match access-group name XYZ

class-map match-any C-ABC 
 match access-group name ABC

policy-map Active 
class C-XYZ 
 police cir 67600000 bc 70000000 conform-action transmit exceed-action drop

class C-ABC 
police cir 38800000 bc 40000000 conform-action transmit exceed-action drop

class class-default 
police cir 33000000 bc 61000000 conform-action transmit exceed-action drop
```

Then i can apply this police on interface ... My Question can i can apply like this using Linux CentOs ..

Thanks in advance

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the same thing in Linux by using [iptables](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables).